# New to programming (C)

Tags: c

Hi everyone I'm new to programming and I was reading "The C Book" by Mike Banahan, Declan Brady, and Mark Doran (1991) and I'm having trouble understanding exercise 1.2.
The question is "Using Example 1.2 as a pattern, write a program that prints prime pairs - a pair of prime numbers that differ by 2, for example 11 and 13, 29 and 31."
I went ahead and checked in the back of the book for the answer and I understand most of the code but not the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(){
    int this_number, divisor, not_prime;
    int last_prime;
    this_number = 3;
    last_prime = 3;
    printf("1, 3 is a prime pair\n");
    while(this_number < 10000){
        divisor = this_number /2;
        not_prime = 0;
        while(divisor >1){
            if(this_number % divisor == 0){
                not_prime = 1;
                divisor = 0;}
            else divisor = divisor -1;}
            if(not_prime == 0){
                if(this_number == last_prime +2)
                printf("%d, %d is a prime pair\n", last_prime, this_number);
                last_prime = this_number;}
            this_number= this_number +1;}
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
```

if this_number is 3 then shouldn't last_prime (which is also 3) + 2 = 5, which would be false and the print statement shouldn't execute?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: If you're brand new to programming, I would suggest learning another language first such as Python or Ruby, then come back to C. This will allow you to learn basic programming logic and syntax without having to simultaneously deal with the very complicated problem of memory management and C's funny string handling.

Comment: Do you understand what the line `this_number = this_number + 1;` does?

Comment: (By the way -- I'm voting to close this, since the question doesn't contain the necessary code to understand it. Linking to a screenshot of the code is *not* an acceptable substitute.)

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question.

Comment: @ruakh yea it adds 1 to 3 at the end of the program so that it loops - typed in the code for you, sorry about that

Answer (score -1):

> if this_number is 3 then shouldn't last_prime (which is also 3) + 2 = 5, which would be false and the print statement shouldn't execute?

Yes, when the program starts `this_number` and `last_prime` are 3.  That statement will be false and it will not execute because 3 is not 5.  This is correct, because it's looking for prime pairs like 3 and 5, 5 and 7, 11 and 13.  3 and 3 are not a prime pair.

A prime pair will happen in two more iterations when `this_number` is 5 and `last_prime` is 3.  After that `last_prime` will become 5 and `this_number` will move on to 6.

Comment: I understand thank you! So when this_number hits 11 the program will skip the next printf statement since this_number is 11 and last_prime (7) +2 is 9. However last_prime = this_number changes 11 to the next last_prime so when this_number hits 13 the printf(this_number == last_prime+2) statement becomes true and it prints.